# How can I statistically compare a lightcurve data set with the simulated lightcurve?

Tags: python

With python I want to compare a simulated light curve with the real light curve. It should be mentioned that the measured data contain gaps and outliers and the time steps are not constant. The model, however, contains constant time steps. 
In a first step I would like to compare with a statistical method how similar the two light curves are. Which method is best suited for this?

In a second step I would like to fit the model to my measurement data. However, the model data is not calculated in Python but in an independent software. Basically, the model data depends on four parameters, all of which are limited to a certain range, which I am currently feeding mannualy to the software (planned is automatic).
What is the best method to create a suitable fit? 
A "Brute-Force-Fit" is currently an option that comes to my mind.

This link "https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Iiaf.jpg" provides three different plots. The simulated lightcurve, the actual measurement and lastly both together. The simulation is not good, but by playing with the parameters one can get an acceptable result. Which means the phase and period are the same, magnitude is in the same order and even the specular flashes should occur at the same period.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you're asking a more foundational question that could be better answered in https://datascience.stackexchange.com/, rather than something specific to Python.

That said, as a data science layperson, this may be a problem suited for gradient descent with a mean-square-error cost function. You initialize the parameters of the curve (possibly randomly), then calculate the square error at your known points.

Then you make tiny changes to each parameter in turn, and calculate how the cost function is affected. Then you change all the parameters (by a tiny amount) in the direction that decreases the cost function. Repeat this until the parameters stop changing.

(Note that this might trap you in a local minimum and not work.)

More information: https://towardsdatascience.com/implement-gradient-descent-in-python-9b93ed7108d1

**Edit:** I overlooked this part

> The simulation is not good, but by playing with the parameters one can get an acceptable result. Which means the phase and period are the same, magnitude is in the same order and even the specular flashes should occur at the same period.

Is the simulated curve just a sum of sine waves, and are the parameters just phase/period/amplitude of each? In this case what you're looking for is the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) of your signal, which is very easy to calculate with numpy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/fftpack.html

Comment: maybe, maybe not, I think it is very dangerous to fixate onto a model before inspecting the data objectively. every dataset has its own caveats and there is no one model to fit them all... unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, this is just one idea for a first approach. This is definitely more of a question for one of the science StackExchanges than a programming question.

Comment: Yes, it is, and the Idea is quite reasonable. I just wanted to give a hint for OP not to think he can save his problem based on an answer to a super broad SO question ;)